# Why vuex4.0 not work as hooks inside Vue3 onMounted async function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sockets, vuex

bar1(), bar2(), bar3() are three **separated** situation, I would like to **choose one of them** as the real **bar()** when foo() completed, then sent to web socket, and then stored callback value by vuex.

1.bar1(): I found if I put any bar1() into onMounted scope, it couldn't work, store turn to be undefined.

2.bar2(): I pass argument "store" in XXX.vue into bar2(), and it works.

3.bar3(): Strangely, it could work if bar3() not in onMounted scope, although this is not async function, without waiting for foo(), not the way I expect.

msg_state store something in store.state..., and I would like to commit it to update its value

**Questions**:

1. What's the difference between bar1(), bar2(), bar3()
2. Why bar2() as bar() could work but bar1() as bar() could not work?
3. It's because bar3() is inside setup() scope rather than onMounted() scope?

```
// In socket.js
// not work
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
export const bar1 = async(input) =>  {
// store is undefined
const store = useStore()
socket = io(url)
    socket.on('message', (msg)  = {
        // commit is not defined
        store.commit("msg_state", msg) 
    })
}

// work
export const bar2 = async(input, store) =>  {
    socket = io(url)
    socket.on('message', (msg)  = {
        store.commit("msg_state", msg) 
    })
}

// work but not async
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
export const bar3 = (input) =>  {
const store = useStore()
    socket = io(url)
    socket.on('message', (msg)  = {
        store.commit("msg_state", msg) 
    })
}

//In XXX.vue
import bar from '@/util/socket.js'
...
export default {
    setup() {
        const xxx = reactive({input: oldVal})
        const store = useStore()
        onMounted(async () => {
        //{input: oldVal}
        await foo()
        //{input: newVal}

        // option1: bar1 as bar
        await bar1(xxx.input) // counldn't work

        // option2: bar2 as bar
        await bar2(xxx.input, store) // this could work

        })
        // option3: bar3 as bar
        bar3(xxx.input) // this could work but not async
    }
}
```

Comment: The code doesn't use `input`. It's unclear why `bar` can be used multiple times because it does the same thing across the app.

Comment: Sorry sir, I just edit my  pseudo code and description,  it was not complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bar1` and `bar3` are also wrong because hooks are generally supposed to be called in `setup`. `bar2` doesn't need access to the whole store.

Making functions `async` is semantic mistake because they are asynchronous but don't involve promises. Moreover, there is `message` subscription and it cannot be translated to promises, unless it's one-time event.

In case it's one-time, that `commit` is used outside an action means that store-specific business logic scatters over the application. The whole `bar` could be Vuex action:

```
const bar = async ({ commit,  state }, input ) =>  {
  // socket is likely a part of state
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    socket.once('message', (msg) => {
      commit("msg_state", msg) 
      resolve(msg);
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: My apology for ambiguous description and not complete  pseudo code, I  would like to choose one of these three fucntion as bar() in setup scope,  and just bar2() works, is the bar1() 's store not in setup() function that cause store in bar1() is undefined?  And the bar3() could work because it's called in setup() scope?

Comment: That is, I should use await new Promise to correct  bar2  for my commit?

Comment: It depends. You didn't specify if it's one-time or not, and how `input` affects it, which is the most important part here. Is `message` supposed to be received multiple times inside bar? Then it's incorrect to use promises and async/await at all.

Comment: The message could update a "chatroom" informations multiple times , I just remove the incorrect async/await syntax and it works well, thanks for your clear explanation !  BTW, is there the only way to move my bar() into action, rather than pass store, which I got from XXX.vue setup(), as arguments of  bar() in individual file socket.js?

Comment: If you don't reuse `bar`, it doesn't make much sense to extract it into a function outside the component and so there will be no problems with arguments you describe. A subscription for unspecific event such as `message` looks like global behaviour for the app and likely should be done only once. Maybe in app component. If it's accessed in multiple places, this probably should happen on store initialization in app component in order for a message to be available through store.